# ¿Cómo hago un merge con más de una variable clave y cierta condición en la clave?

Tags: r

Necesito combinar dos dataframes en R utilizando más de una variable clave. Una de esas variables es una fecha, que no coincide exactamente sino que tiene que me tiene que unir con la anterior más cercana.

DF1

```
ID        DATE_REGSITRO  NOMBRE   
 115477    2020-03-31     Pablo   
 115478    2022-05-29     Sebastian    
 115479    2020-06-29     Carlos
 115479    2022-12-29      Carlos
```

DF2

```
ID        DATE_SCORE      SCORE    
 115477    2020-02-03     554    
 115478    2022-03-15     635      
 115479    2020-04-15     638      
 115479    2022-10-15     789     
 115479    2023-02-15     885
```

**DF_MERGE**

```
  ID       DATE_REGSITRO  NOMBRE    SCORE
 115477    2020-03-31     Pablo      554
 115478    2022-05-29     Sebastian  635
 115479    2020-06-29     Carlos     638
 115479    2022-12-29     Carlos     789
```

Answer (score 1):

Con `tidyverse` es bastante simple:

```
library(tidyverse)

DF1 %>% 
  # Generamos una relcion n a m
  # Pero finalmente obtenemos la fecha única en cada caso
  left_join(DF2, 
            by = join_by(ID),
            relationship = "many-to-many") %>% 
  filter(DATE_REGSITRO > DATE_SCORE) %>% 
  group_by(ID, DATE_REGSITRO, NOMBRE) %>% 
  summarise(DATE_SCORE = max(DATE_SCORE)) %>% 
  # Obtenemos el score en una relación 1 a 1 
  left_join(DF2, 
            by = join_by(ID, DATE_SCORE))
```

Comentarios:

- La primer parte es obtener `ID` y el `DATE_SCORE` que corresponde
- Con lo anterior ya podemos hacer un relación 1 a 1 para obtener el `SCORE`